# PHP tidy turn off code improvement

Tags: php, html, tidy

I want to use PHP's tidy just for making the HTML output more readable, but not for any 'optimizations' of my code. In my opinion I am responsible for providing well - formed HTML, not readable HTML.

So how can I turn this behavior off?

Comment: Sorry, IMHO if you're the developer, it's your responsibility to provide readable HTML too.

Comment: How do you deliver unreadable code to clients and keep them or their developers happy?

Comment: Well I want to do so by using tidy. But never the less, it is not my responsibility at all, because the intendation etc. doesn't matter to browsers. Some sites even remove ALL spaces, tabs an \n's to produce a smaller output.

Comment: If not you, who is writing the code, is responsible for writing readable and (therefore) maintainable code, who is? Sites removing indents, line breaks, etc., is probably using some sort of add-on to their CMS or manipulating the output before flushing the output buffer.

Comment: Before I got to my current job they had a custom CMS built by another company, the CMS created a situation like you are referring too, "not readable HTML".  It has created more headaches than I can tell you.  Needless to say we will never have them work on another project for us.  Just FYI if you are trying to establish a long term client relationship.

Comment: The HTML is of course readable, it's just doesnt look that nicely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like it isn't possible. Feel free to post a better answer.